# How to convert string (Twitter4j format) to Java Date

Tags: java, twitter4j

I would like to extract date and year from the following string and convert it to a Data Object in Java.

> Mon Jul 07 19:18:26 CEST 2014

How can I extract only date and year (in this case, 2014-07-07) from the text in a sophisticated way?

Comment: Try this: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/4216745/java-string-to-date-conversion

Comment: You are receiving a JSON and transforming it to string right? Have you tried using ParseUtil, getDate(java.lang.String name, twitter4j.org.json.JSONObject json)?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```
SimpleDateFormat s = new SimpleDateFormat("dd/MMM/yyyy");
String dateInString = "Mon Jul 07 19:18:26 CEST 2014";

        SimpleDateFormat myFormat = new SimpleDateFormat("yyyy-MM-dd");

                    try {
                        Date date = s.parse(dateInString.split(" ")[2]+"/"+dateInString.split(" ")[1]+"/"+dateInString.split(" ")[5]);
                        System.out.println(new SimpleDateFormat("YYYY-MM-dd").format(date));
                    } catch (ParseException e) {
                        // TODO Auto-generated catch block
                        e.printStackTrace();
                    }
```

This should work for you, I splitted your String, then put it to a date format and then formatted it the way you wanted it to be, assumed you wanted the months as the second parameter after the year, if thats not the case you can simply change the 'MM' to 'dd' and the 'dd' to 'MM'.

Answer (score 0):

For Java 7 or below, use a [`SimpleDateFormat`](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/text/SimpleDateFormat.html) for parsing and formatting:

```
Locale dateLocale = Locale.US;
SimpleDateFormat inFormat = new SimpleDateFormat("E MMM dd HH:mm:ss z yyyy", dateLocale);
Date date = inFormat.parse("Mon Jul 07 19:18:26 CEST 2014");
SimpleDateFormat outFormat = new SimpleDateFormat("yyyy-MM-dd", dateLocale);
System.out.println(outFormat.format(date));
```

Since Java 8, you can use [`DateTimeFormatter`](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/time/format/DateTimeFormatter.html):

```
Locale dateLocale = Locale.US;
DateTimeFormatter inFormatter = DateTimeFormatter.ofPattern("E MMM dd HH:mm:ss z yyyy", dateLocale);
TemporalAccessor date = inFormatter.parse("Mon Jul 07 19:18:26 CEST 2014");
DateTimeFormatter outFormatter = DateTimeFormatter.ISO_LOCAL_DATE;
System.out.println(outFormatter.format(date));
```